# TinyMCE does not initiate when SimpleModal opens a second time

Tags: asp.net, tinymce, simplemodal

I did some searching and found a few people with the same issue but no actual answer.

I have a aspx page that is using SimpleModal.  Inside this SimpleModal window, I have a TextBox control in textarea mode.  I am using TinyMCE to transform that control into a RichTextBox.

When opening the modal for the first time, TinyMCE renders correct, however, if I close the SimpleModal window and then reopen it, its back to the basic TextArea control.

Here is my HTML for the control

```
<div id="bio-modal" style="display:none;">
    <h3>Member Bio</h3>
    <p>Introduce yourself to other members by writing a small member bio.  When other members search for your, this bio will be shown.</p>
    <p>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBioContent" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="395px" Height="300px" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSaveProfile" runat="server" Text="Save Profile" OnClick="btnSaveProfile_Click" />
    </p>
</div>
```

There is my code used to open SimpleModal and initiate TinyMCE.

```
    function showModal(which)
    {
        switch (which) {
            case "bio":
                $('#bio-modal').modal({
                    appendTo: 'form',
                    minWidth: 420,
                    minHeight: 460,
                    onShow: function () {
                        tinymce.init({ selector: '#<% = txtBioContent.ClientID %>' });
                    }
                });
                break;
            case "pw":
                $('#password-modal').modal({
                    appendTo: 'form',
                    minWidth: 200,
                    minHeight: 200
                });
                break;
            case "email":
                $('#email-modal').modal({
                    appendTo: 'form',
                    minWidth: 200,
                    minHeight: 200
                });
                break;
        }
    }
```

Any help in this area would be greatly appreciated!

Phillip

Answer (score 0):

okay... so it seems you have to remove the TinyMCE control once the SimpleModal window is closed.

```
tinymce.remove();
```

This is fine if you have a button / link inside the popup to close the modal, but if you use the top right (canned) X button, it will not work.  You will need to modify the SimpleModal source.

Thanks